# Prove that $Ae + B/e$ is irrational.

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

> Prove that $Ae + B/e$ is irrational. Here A and B are non-zero integers.

We know that the sum of two irrational numbers need not be an irrational number.
For example $\sqrt2+1$ and $1-\sqrt2$ are irrational numbers. But there sum $(\sqrt2+1)+ (1-\sqrt2)=2\enspace (2 \in \mathbb{Q})$ is not an irrational number.
But for this problem, I am finding difficulty even how to begin with, which will slowly lead me to the proof.

Comment: $e$ Is transendental. IF $A$, $B$ and integers and $q=Ae+\tfrac{B}{e}$ is rational then $e$ is a solution of the algebraic equation $Ax^3-qx+B=0$ equations which is not possible.

Comment: @JohnOmielan    Yes,A and B are non-zero integers.

Comment: @OliverDiaz $Ae^3 -qe + B = Ae^3 -Ae^2$. did you mean $Ax^2-qx+B$?

Comment: @CSquared: yes, that is what I meant: $x^3$ should be $x^2$.

Comment: Joseph Liouville gave such proofs for the first time. I have described a few such proofs  in my blog posts (with reference to Liouville's original paper). Check [post 1](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/03/proof-that-e-is-not-a-quadratic-irrationality.html?m=0), [post 2](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/03/another-proof-that-e-squared-is-irrational.html?m=0) and [post 3](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/03/proof-that-e-squared-is-not-a-quadratic-irrationality.html?m=0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose that $Ae + B/e$ is rational. Then $Ae + B/e = p/q$ for some $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $Ae^2 - \frac{p}{q} e + B = 0$. Clearing denominators gives us $e$ as a root of $Aqx^2 - px + Bq$ which is impossible since $e$ is transcendental.

Comment: This is correct but would have to be described as overkill, because the fact that $e$ is transcendental is *way* more sophisticated than what the question asks for.

Answer (score 5):

Have you seen the proof that $e$ is irrational by using the series for $e$?  If so, only a fairly small modification is needed.  If $Ae+B/e$ is rational, then by clearing denominators we can get
$$ae+be^{-1}=c$$
for some integers $a,b,c$.  Writing
$$e=1+\frac1{1!}+\cdots+\frac1{n!}+R_n\ ,\qquad
  e^{-1}=1-\frac1{1!}+\cdots\pm\frac1{n!}+S_n$$
leads to
$$cn!-a(n!+\cdots+1)-b(n!-\cdots\pm1)=(aR_n+bS_n)n!\ .$$
The left hand side is an integer, and if you can show that $0<|{\rm RHS}|<1$ then you have a contradiction.  You may need to consider various cases, e.g., whether $n$ is even or odd.

All this and more in [my recent book](https://www.routledge.com/Irrationality-and-Transcendence-in-Number-Theory/Angell/p/book/9780367628376)!  (Moderators feel free to remove if free plugs are not allowed.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with your book. In the appendix to the book Algebra, by Serg Lang, he states, without proof, a general theorem and from it, proves the transcendence of $e$ in ONE line, then the transcendence of $\pi$ in TWO lines, and then the Gelfond-Schneider theorem in THREE  lines.

Comment: @David          I am familiar with the above proof of proving e to be irrational. It was a nice intelligent way to use it and prove $Ae+B/e$ to be irrational. Thanks for your answer too!

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I don't have access to Lang's book right now, but the transcendence of $e$ is quite hard, $\pi$ is harder and Gelfond-Schneider is very hard. I suspect this general theorem which Lang has stated WITHOUT PROOF is something extremely powerful, and difficult to prove.  So you can't reasonably call that a one-line proof of the transcendence of $e$ - make it one line, plus however many were needed to prove the other theorem.

Comment: Well, yes, I expect the proof of the quoted theorem would be formidable. But the 3 results really do follow from it with amazing brevity, like magic

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I'm sure they do and it's very interesting.  But in terms of proving transcendence of $e$ etc, that really isn't the point.

Answer (score 2):

An elementary proof, without using the (deep) theorem that $e$ is transcendental. Suppose $A,B,C\in\Bbb Q$ and $Ae+B/e=C.$ We show that $A=B=0.$

Take $D\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $A'=AD,B'=BD,C'=CD$ are in $\Bbb Z.$

For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ we have $n!C'=n!eA'+n!(1/e)B'=E_n+\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty}(A'+(-1)^jB')n!/j!$ where $E_n\in\Bbb Z.$ So we have $\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty}(A'+(-1)^jB')n!/j!\in\Bbb Z.$

For brevity let $\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty}(A'+(-1)^jB')n!/j!=R_n.$

We have  $(n+1)R_n-R_{n+1}=A'+(-1)^{n+1}B'.$ We also have $\lim_{n\to\infty}R_n=0$ but  $R_n\in\Bbb Z,$ so $R_n=0$ for all but finitely many $n.$ So take $n$ large enough that $R_n=R_{n+1}=R_{n+2}=0.$ Then $$A'+(-1)^{n+1}B'=(n+1)R_n-R_{n+1}=0$$  $$A'+(-1)^{n+2}B'=(n+2)R_{n+1}-R_{n+2}=0$$ which imply $A'=B'=0.$